# page scrolling jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to make page scrolling for specific div, see the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4GHq2/2/

I want to make so that when you click on 3 from the first page, it scrolls to sec3 directly without scrolling through sec2, so it appears as one flip.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Can't you just follow the same paradigm as the example you gave? Maybe I am not understanding your entire question.

Comment: You want it to just scroll to the clicked div without the animation?

Comment: I want to make 1 go to three with the same smoothness as sec1 go to sec2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a viewport wrapped around the sections, the easiest thing to do then would be to hide section 2 before you start your scroll.

**EDIT:** Updated the Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/4GHq2/22/ It's not perfect yet, but the base is there.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor this a bit to your liking, but how about this example?

http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/4GHq2/14/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to make 1 go to three with the same smoothness as sec1 go to sec2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a jump and not a scroll. You could do this with a simple link tag with something like

```
   <a href="#sec3">3</a>
```